# Why do we put exifData property in metadata?

Tags: html, metadata, semantic-web, json-ld

Can somebody help to understand why do we put exidData` as an attribute for metadata, since I don't really see the point?

```
  <div property="exifData" typeOf="PropertyValue">
          <meta property="name" content="Exposure Time">
          <meta property="value" content="1/659 sec.">
      </div>
      <div property="exifData" typeOf="PropertyValue">
          <meta property="name" content="FNumber">
          <meta property="value" content="f/4.0">
      </div>
      <div property="exifData" typeOf="PropertyValue">
          <meta property="name" content="MaxApertureValue">
          <meta property="value" content="2.00">
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe why you think there is no point? -- You do see a point in providing metadata in structured data, I guess? Why not also Exif-based metadata?

Comment: @unor I want to understand the logic and rational behind this `exidData`, why do we put this, can u explain for me or send me the link?

Comment: But for giving you an answer, we would need to know what exactly you wonder about `exifData`. Schema.org has many properties for [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) -- do you see in point in all of them except `exifData`? Can you try to describe why?